# Return selected columns in deep nested relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and trying to return data from multiple tables using a join.

I'm using 3 models / tables, Customer, Business and Website which are related as follows:

In Customer.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
  public function businesses()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Business');
  }
}
```

In Business.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Model
{
  public function customer() 
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
  }

  public function websites()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Website');
  }
}
```

And in Website.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Website extends Model
{  
  public function business() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Business');
  }
}
```

So a `Customer` can have many `Businesses` which can have many `Websites`.

Now I'm trying to return certain columns from `Customer`, `Business` and `Website` in (ideally) one Eloquent request. I know I can return all columns from all tables using a simple eager load like so:

```
Customer::with('businesses.websites');
```

However I only want to return certain columns and return an array of arrays like so:

```
[
  0 => {
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Smith,
    'email' => 'js@test.com',
    'businesses' => [ 
      0 => {
        'name' => 'Smith Ltd'
        'websites' =>  [
          0 => {
            'domain' => 'smithltd',
            'tld' => '.co.uk'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  } ...
]
```

i.e ignoring ids, foreign keys, created_at timestamps etc etc.

I've been trying to achieve this using the following code (and variations thereof):

```
  Customer::with([
    'businesses' => function ($q) {
      $q->select('id', 'customer_id')->pluck('name');
    },
    'businesses.websites' => function ($q) {
      $q->select('id', 'business_id')->pluck('domain', 'tld');
    }
  ])->get();
```

But this is returning `id`, `customer_id` and `business_id` too which I don't want. As far as I know I need to add the `foreign_key` and `primary_key` in the `select` query for the query to work but is there a way to remove it from the collection that is ultimately returned? Or is there a better way to approach this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216763/laravel-many-to-many-unexpected-result-set-on-select/30218621#30218621

Comment: This isn't a PHP answer, but have you considered making a database view for this information, and a model that references the view for the specific use case?

Comment: Also, if your use case for this is only to return via API, then you might consider Fractal

Comment: Hi @JoshPetitt, do you mean create a new table in my database which holds all this information?

Comment: @dbatten, for my first comment, I recommended a database view (this is a database thing that lets you perform the joins on database side).  I would do this if there is a very specific use case.  It may be easier than trying to do the joins in laravel.  For the second comment, if you are okay with getting more data than you need from the database, but only want to render certain fields to the client as part of a JSON API, then Fractal is a very good tool for this.

Comment: @JoshPetitt thanks for recommending Fractal. Just trying out now, it's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: have you get this answer? @dbatten

Comment: @AgnesPalit can't remember exactly what i did as it was a while ago but i think i went with fractal initially then migrated to [laravel resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a rray_merge with you Business Model

create new function

```
  public function getArrayWithCustomerAndWebsites()
  {
    return array_merge( "customer" => $this->customer(), etc..... );
  }
```

Hope it help you !